# Template class giving error with primitive data types

Tags: java, primitive-types, template-classes

Gives "non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context"

This is the code below for template class

```
public class BiHashMap<K1, K2, V>{

    private final Map<K1, Map<K2, V>> mMap;

    public BiHashMap() {
        mMap = new HashMap<K1, Map<K2, V>>();
    }

    public V put(K1 key1, K2 key2, V value) {
        Map<K2, V> map;
        if (mMap.containsKey(key1)) {
            map = mMap.get(key1);
        } else {
            map = new HashMap<K2, V>();
            mMap.put(key1, map);
        }

        return map.put(key2, value);
    }

}
```

---

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    BiHashMap<double,double,double> table1 = new BiHashMap<double,double,double>();
    table1.put(0.375,1,350);
```

I tried making a new class for double but the error remained

```
public class dbble{
    double number;

    dbble(double x){
        number=x;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the error log?

Comment: You can't use **primitive types** as template parameters (Java doesn't have template parameters, you mean generic types), you must use the wrapper types.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch are right. Just change `new BiHashMap<double,double,double>();` to `new BiHashMap<Double,Double,Double>();`

Comment: Change your `put` function to static, because you can not call a non static function inside a static function.

Comment: @TuyenNguyen Tried doing this but got this new error                    'Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - Erroneous tree type: <any> '

Answer (score 0):

I have test your code above and edit it to make it run: (You have to put the `main` function inside the `class`, you need to use `wrapper type` for `double`, and cast the value you put to when you call the function).

```
public class BiHashMap<K1, K2, V> {

private final Map<K1, Map<K2, V>> mMap;

public BiHashMap() {
    mMap = new HashMap<K1, Map<K2, V>>();
}

public V put(K1 key1, K2 key2, V value) {
    Map<K2, V> map;
    if (mMap.containsKey(key1)) {
        map = mMap.get(key1);
    } else {
        map = new HashMap<K2, V>();
        mMap.put(key1, map);
    }

    return map.put(key2, value);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    BiHashMap<Double, Double, Double> table1 = new BiHashMap<Double, Double, Double>();
    table1.put(0.375, Double.valueOf(1), Double.valueOf(350));
}
}
```